# Dúvida de como usar a função cubic-bezier() do CSS

Tags: css

Não estou entendendo direito como alterar a velocidade da animação ao longo, em que ela está sendo executada. O gráfico abaixo está ilustrando uma valocidade de animação utilizando a função `cubic-bezier()`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Linha cinza**: representa os eixos.

**Linha laranja**: representa a curva.

**Linhas e pontos azuis**: representa o controle para modelar a curva.

E para poder utilizar a função `cubic-bezier()` teria que pegar as coordenadas dos pontos azuis que são os `P1` e `P2` como a função `cubic-bezier()` está definida em cartesiano, então tem que definir os eixos `x` e `y` de `P1` e `x` e `y` de `P2`, o `P0` é aonde começa a velocidade da animação e o `P3` é aonde termina.

**Exemplo**

```
cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

`x1` é a coordenada `x` do ponto de controle `p1`.

`y1` é a coordenada `y` do ponto de controle `p1`.

`x2` é a coordenada `x` do ponto de controle `p2`.

`y2` é a coordenada `y` do ponto de controle `p2`.

Ok, com base nessas informações acima, como quando eu sei que a curva vai estar rápida, lenta, normal, etc ?. Quando eu modelo a curva para cima ela vai indicar o que, rápida ou lenta ? ou quando eu modelo para baixo, como eu sei a velocidade dela ? deu para entender o que eu quero dizer ? tipo eu sei que tem vários sites que te auxiliam a criar essas curvas como, por exemplo, o site [cubic-bezier](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67) ou o site [roblaplaca](http://www.roblaplaca.com/examples/bezierBuilder/), mas não é esse o caso, no gráfico acima a curva fica mais para baixo, isso indica o que ela está mais rápida ou o que? por favor preciso entender apenas isso!

Comment: @hugocsl, valeu pelo intuito de ajudar, mas essa resposta não resolveu minha dúvida.

Comment: Agora vc vai entender http://prntscr.com/p2s232 ! Depois testa com os valores ao contrario, e vc vai ver que começa super lenta e termina rápido https://cubic-bezier.com/#.75,0,1,.01. Não tem segredo. E para ser `linear`, contante na velocidadeXprogresso ela tem que começar em 0,0 e terminar em 1,1, https://cubic-bezier.com/#0,0,1,1, não tem mistério, tá explicado lá, mas é complicado de entender a primeira vesta mesmo

Comment: Desculpa amigo, mais para ser sincero eu não entendi!

Comment: Acho que vc não entendeu pq vc acha que o cubic-bezier controla o tempo, só que não, o tempo é controlado pelo https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration e se a animação tem 1 segundo, ela sempre vai ter 1 segundo. Já para vc controlar como vai ser **o progresso** da animação dentro desse **1 segundo** vc usa o  cubic-bezier() https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function depois de ler isso veja novamente a imagem do outro comentário acima e vc vai entender. Talvez depois disso vc vai entender pq é duplicada. E leia os links da documentação

Comment: Value @hugocsl, li a documentação agora entendi tava conplicado mais deu certo, tudo de bom!